# Difference in cost between external contract as state variable vs. instantiation of contract?

Tags: solidity, state-variable

For

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface ExternalContract {
    function initialize() external;
}

contract Test {
  ExternalContract c;
  
  constructor(address externalContractAddress) public {
      c = ExternalContract(externalContractAddress);
  }

  function testA() public {
    c.initialize();
  }

  function testB(address externalContractAddress) public {
    ExternalContract(externalContractAddress).initialize();
  }
}
```

Is there a preferred option in terms of cost between `testA` and `testB`? I can see that B allows you to save on a state variable, but don't know whether on the spot instantiation is somehow more expensive.

Comment: Please rewrite the code in this question as a working example. The `address` keyword cannot be used as an argument, so rename it to begin with. Then, please explain where it is coming from (i.e., a state-variable or a function argument, because at present it is neither, which doesn't make any sense).

Comment: @goodvibration done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `c` being a state-variable, this:

```
c.initialize();
```

Costs 800 more gas units than this:

```
ExternalContract(externalContractAddress).initialize();
```

Because it includes loading the value of `c` from storage (i.e., an additional SLOAD operation).